# .NET assembly is not loaded from GAC

Tags: asp.net, .net, global-assembly-cache

I am banging my head against the desk for the best part of the day and cannot for the life of me understand this. An assembly that is clearly in the Global Application Cache is not found by the web app that is trying to use it. Everything I can find on the web assumes or explicitly states that there is no way to *avoid* loading from GAC, it's global and mandatory behaviour. And yet, in my case, it just seems to fail.

Assembly in GAC:
[image]

Error when an .aspx page tries to use it:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (C:\Program Files\FMS\GeoPortal2\reporting\web.config line 34) ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler..ctor(VirtualPath configPath, Boolean supportLocalization, String outputAssemblyName)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

**UPDATE**: I tried to set "Copy Local" to "true" for the missing .dll so that it would be included in the project on build. Now I get a different error:

```
System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005): c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\geo2\e2a70b87\2b9be05\App_Web_reportviewer.aspx.733fdbe7.njrhyncf.0.cs(254): error CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\geo2\e2a70b87\2b9be05\assembly\dl3\4e808648\047538f8_8e06d101\CrystalDecisions.Web.DLL'
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

So the situation is that when the .dll is in the project, IIS finds both that **and** the GAC one, and complains about the conflict. When the assembly is not in the project, IIS can't find either. In addition, trying to open the GAC path that the error message shows (c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web) gives a "does not exist" error.

I am even more lost than I was before. What could cause such a weird behavior?

Comment: Did you had installed CrystalReports (standalone package) into server?

Comment: Also, did you had installed LOG4NET32 into server? Don´t ask me why, but I believe it´s necessary - at least in my case it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure exactly what helped, but I uninstalled and reinstalled everything CrystalReports-related and then went over everything CrystalReports-related in the .config files, tweaking anything that looked out of place. Specifically, the last thing that I fixed before it started working was a missing `PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304` in the `CrystalDecisions.Web` assembly reference.

Answer (score 2):

The GAC you opened is for .NET 2/3/3.5. .NET 4 and above use another location. Make sure you use gacutil.exe in .NET 4 SDK or VS 2010 (and above) Prompt to install the assembly.

Comment: gacutil.exe is not a good solution because this problem is on the deployment server which does not (and is not supposed to) have any development tools on it. I doubt that the client will agree to install SDKs or a whole Visual Studio instance on their production environment just for this. Also, please see the update to the original post.

Comment: @ModusOperandi didn't you know it can be simply copied to that machine and use? No need to install a big SDK. Of course Microsoft has Web Deploy for web app deployment which solves all kind of issues like this.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try that. But I would still like to understand what the problem is, especially considering what I wrote in the update. It seems a very weird behavior and I'd like to fix it properly rather than just manually working around a third-party installer.

Comment: @ModusOperandi you enter the darkness by using a third party component like this one. Only by following its vendor documentation you can find a safe and supported approach to deploy the app, while what I am suggesting is just a dirty hack. Your update is even more difficult to understand without touching it, so I won't comment much on that.